# Why is Azure Service Bus Message missing fields?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I am using Microsoft Azure Service Bus. I am publishing boolean messages (non-nullable) as part of the message. Sometimes these fields are missing but other times the message is in the correct format. It's not a size issue as the messages are only 3KB in size. Does anyone know what might be happening?

Thank you!

Comment: How do you serialize your message? Provide something that would help to understand the behaviour.

Comment: I'm using MassTransit.Publish()
https://masstransit-project.com/usage/transports/azure-sb.html

Comment: Ok, how does your message gets serialized? Your question is too broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that MassTransit does not serialize default values unless you override its serializer. For example, `int x = 0`  would not be serialized because its default value is zero. Here is a link to the github issue in case anyone runs into it

https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/issues/695

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.